# How to get global IPv6 address via batch-file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to get the Global IPv6 address of a computer stored inside a variable.

I found this code, but it only gives the Link-Local address.

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -6 -n 1 ^| findstr "["') do (set ipv6=%%a)
```

Comment: [Here is Microsoft's documentation about IPv6 configuration using the native tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726952.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In vbscript we can do something like this :

To get ***OnlyIPv6Address.vbs***

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled = 'True'")
For Each objIP in colSettings
   For i=LBound(objIP.IPAddress) to UBound(objIP.IPAddress)
      If InStr(objIP.IPAddress(i),":") <> 0 Then msgbox objIP.IPAddress(i)
   Next
Next
```

And to get ***OnlyIPv4Address.vbs***

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled = 'True'")
For Each objIP in colSettings
   For i=LBound(objIP.IPAddress) to UBound(objIP.IPAddress)
      If InStr(objIP.IPAddress(i),":") = 0 Then Msgbox objIP.IPAddress(i)
   Next
Next
```